# Automation of tasks in Linux

Tags: linux, automation

Is there any recommended software to automatize certain tasks in linux?

For example:

- Tell the weather forecast at a particular time of the day
- enable a radio
- open a file also at some time of the day

Comment: Cron is probably the easiest way to automate tasks. It can be run either per-user or system-wide.

Comment: Always depends on the "trigger", but most things already ship with the system: Cron for time-based stuff, UDev for device-based things (aka "whenever I connect X, do Z), iNotify for "whenever a file gets created/updated here, do …", then there's also init.d/systemd and more. I'm not aware of a "software on top" to manage all those (prividing a GUI and more). So if you want a software recommendation (which is what this site is about), you'd need to be a bit more specific on what you need (not that easy, I know)…

Comment: i'm taking a look at all of them. thank you guys! just want to automatize things a little bit...

Comment: What kinds of triggers do you need? For instance, if a stock price goes over XYZ, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [Node Red](https://nodered.org/) if you're feeling a bit more ambitious. Node-Red is a NodeJS-based system for arbitrary workflows. It can be run many different platforms.

For example, if you want to get the weather at a specific time of day, you could see for example the [DarkSky flow](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-darksky)

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of triggers it supports? A screenshot showing the "Tell the weather forecast at a particular time of the day" scenario would make this a wonderful answer :-)